# C++ ADO stored procedure error: Syntax Error or Access Violation

Tags: c++, sql-server, visual-studio, stored-procedures, ado

I am trying to run an SQL stored procedure through ADO in C++. The procedure is called (for argument's sake) testProcedure and expects two parameters: @param1 and @param2. Here is a trimmed version of the code in the execution method:

```
        m_mCommandParameters[_T("param1")] = _T("foo");
        m_mCommandParameters[_T("param2")] = _T("bar");

        pCommand.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Command));
        pCommand->ActiveConnection = link;
        pCommand->CommandType = adCmdStoredProc;
        pCommand->CommandText = _T("testProcedure");
        pCommand->PutPrepared(true);
        pCommand->NamedParameters = true;

        // Set up the variant to store the parameter values
        VARIANT vParamValue;
        vParamValue.vt = VT_BSTR;

        CString paramCount; // Stores the count for use as parameter name

        // Iterate through set parameters and apply them to command
        map<CString,CString>::iterator mItr;
        for(mItr = m_mCommandParameters.begin(); mItr != m_mCommandParameters.end(); mItr++) {
            paramCount = mItr->first;
            vParamValue.bstrVal = _bstr_t(mItr->second);

            // Append the parameter
            if (mItr->second.IsEmpty()) {
                _variant_t vtNULL;
                vtNULL.vt = VT_NULL;
                pCommand->Parameters->Append(
                    pCommand->CreateParameter(_bstr_t(L"@"+paramCount),adVarChar,adParamInput,10,vtNULL)
                );
            } else {
                pCommand->Parameters->Append(
                    pCommand->CreateParameter(_bstr_t(L"@"+paramCount),adVarWChar,adParamInput,
                                                //commandParameters[i].GetLength()+1,
                                                sizeof(vParamValue),
                                                _bstr_t(vParamValue))
                );
            }

        }

        _variant_t vRecordsAffected;
        pRecordSet = pCommand->Execute(&vRecordsAffected,NULL,adCmdStoredProc);
```

My understanding is that this should essentially execute the following:

```
testProcedure @param1 = 'foo', @param2 = 'bar'
```

If I open SQL management studio and run the above it works fine. But when I try and run the C++ I get the error:

> database error IDispatch error #3092 80040e14 query : testProcedure;
>   [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Syntax error or access violation.

I only have SQL express so don't have SQL profiler; I usually use [Express Profiler](http://expressprofiler.codeplex.com/) but for some reason it doesn't display any trace on stored procedured. So I am not sure how to start debugging this.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't have the time right now to answer this, but as i see it your problem is rooted in several places, including a temp-BSTR that isn't sticking around as long as you need it to, and also passing `,adVarChar,adParamInput,10,vtNULL` as your no-length case, effectively telling ADO the thing in `vtNULL` is a 10-wchar-wide string (which it isn't). If no one else answers before I get to work, I'll try and put something together. It would help if you posted the actual declaration of the stored proc, including parameter defaults if there are any.

Comment: Ok thanks, there are no parameter defaults but I will post the stored procedure code as relevant. I should mention that I am not attempting this with empty values so the NULL condition should not matter at this point, and if I swap `adCmdStoredProc` for `adCmdText` this code works fine to run inline queries (as I do all the time, with multiple parameters).